# Macにvimをインストールして+clientserverにする方法は？

Tags: vim

Macにvimをインストールして+clientserverにしようと考えています。

```
$ brew uninstall vim
```

としてアンインストールの後

```
$ brew install vim --with-client-server
```

としています。でも

```
$ vim --version
```

でオプション内容を確認するとずっと

```
-clientserver
```

のままです。なにがおかしいのでしょうか？

Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep  7 2015 10:01:56)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-729

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macに最初からインストールされている vim を実行しているのだと思います。
[こういった解説](http://bulblub.com/2010/11/18/homebrew%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92%E5%84%AA%E5%85%88%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86/)などを参考に`PATH`を変更するか、どちらの vim を実行するか明示的に指定するようにして下さい。
下記のコマンドは参考です。

```sh
# 環境変数 PATH を表示
echo $PATH
# どこの vim が優先されるか確認
which vim
# Homebrew の vim を実行
/usr/local/bin/vim
# プリインストールの vim を実行
/usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！おっしゃっている通りでした。